# How to register Foundation 5 as AMD module with Require.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, zurb-foundation, amd

I have a Backbone, Marionette and Foundation 5 framework and everything works fine but I can't register Foundation js lib as an AMD module with Require.js. Has anyone successfuly done this? In this example I put just the tooltip component in.

How can I register Foundation 5 as a AMD module with Require.js ?

Here is the code:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl:                './js',
    paths:{
        // Core Libraries
        jquery:             'libs/foundation/vendor/jquery',

        // foundation 5       
        modernizr:          'libs/foundation/vendor/modernizr',

        tooltip:        'libs/foundation/foundation/foundation.tooltip',
            foundation:     'libs/foundation/foundation/foundation'
    },

    shim:{
        // foundation UI framework
        tooltip:    { deps: ['foundation'] },
            foundation:     { deps: ['jquery','modernizr'] },

    },
  });
    require(['jquery','backbone','marionette','app/App','foundation','tooltip'],

    function ($) {

        // Start Marionette Application in desktop mode (default)
        App.start();

        $(document).foundation();

    });
```

Comment: Can you edit your example code down to the minimum to show your problem, without bringing in anything extra? You're more likely to get a response that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently looking into this:

http://matznermatzner.de/en/bernd/2013/12/loading-non-amd-modules-requirejs-part-2-zurb-foundation/

It seems that the way Foundation integrates has changed slightly from older versions, which is why updating Foundation in the existing yeoman-foundation generator prevents it from working.

It may be that you're missing the:

```
{exports: 'Foundation'}
```

from the shim... will test this out soon!

Comment: Link is broken :(